# Is it possible to import some functions to top-level in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'd like to make some functions and macros to be available everywhere, like functions from Kernel module. Is there a place in a program where such import statements could be placed?

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible. You'll have to somehow add the imports; either directly or using a macro.

Comment: You might pull it of with extra compilers and add in each file import statement..